# what's the shortcut to update frames in xcode?

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know what is the shortcut to update frames in xcode?

I know how to do it manually but I am wondering if there's a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It shows beside the menu item

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can find that in Xcode preferences:

```
Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings
```

The default is <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: how do you press the `=` button if you only get `=` doing `shift` + `0`?